# Getting port no of server at which web application is running

Tags: java

I have a task in java for getting the IP address and port no of server at which web application is running .I am able to find the solution of getting the IP address .But I am facing difficulties for finding the port no

```
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        hostname = ip.getHostName();
        // serverName= ip.getHostName();
        serverName = ip.getHostAddress();

        // Socket socket =new Socket();
        // serverName=(((InetSocketAddress)
        // socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()).getAddress()).toString().replace("/","");
        System.out.println("Your current IP address : " + ip);
        System.out.println("Your current Hostname : " + hostname);
        System.out.println("Your current Servername : " + serverName);
```

Can anyone suggest sample piece of code for getting the port no of server at which web application is running.The web application is implemented un java.

Comment: Is it a Spring Boot Application? If it is, this might help : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-running-port

Comment: No .It is not spring boot application. It is normal  web application.